# Flutter & Firebase : Auth disconnects when I refresh

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I use the anonymous auth, and everything works fine but when I want to connect with email and password, as soon as I update with hot reload, I am again anonymous. What I'm doing wrong ?

Here's my main code :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await auth.signInAnonymously();
  runApp(App());
}
```

This is what I use to login :

```
void login() {
    if (_loginForm.currentState!.saveAndValidate()) {
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _email.text.trim(), 
        password: _password.text.trim()
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await auth.signInAnonymously(); // 
  runApp(App());
}
```

Every time your `main` runs, you tell Firebase to sign in as an anonymous user. So if you rerun the app after signing in with Google, calling `signInAnonymously` signs **out** that user to allow it to sign in the anonymous user.

What you'll want to do instead is detect whether a user is already signed in, and only if they're not: sign in anonymously. To [detect authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) use

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
      // TODO: sign in anonymously
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my week again !

Comment: Working fine. But still, when I run the website on Chrome, it returns an 'Unexpected null value', probably because there is no user at the start, I mean before the session connects anonymously. I have to reload the page to make everything work fine, is this going to be a major problem when I will deploy my site?

Comment: I don't think the code in my answer show show that error. If it does, can you point exactly where it comes from? If it comes from somewhere else, it might be better to post a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.